# Access JSP code inside c:if tags?

Tags: html, sql, jsp, tags, compare

I'm trying to display data from a database in a table based on a name you choose on a drop down list on another page. But I cannot understand how you compare a jsp string inside the  tags?
My drop down list is populated from the database on another .jsp page and is called "dropselect". I know you can get the name inside the <%%> but that cannot be accessed inside the  tags?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="newcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Full name</th>
            <th>SQL</th>
            <th>Collection</th>
            <th>Req</th> 
            <th>OS</th> 
            <th>Exam Project</th> 
            <th>Attendance</th>
            <th>Total</th> 
        </tr> 
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
            <%
                String selected = (String)request.getParameter("dropselect");
            %>
            <c:if test="${user.fullname eq selected}">      
                <tr>
                    <td id="id"><c:out value="${user.id}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.fullname}"/></td>
                    <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_sql}"/></td>
                    <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_coll}"/></td>
                    <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_req}"/></td>
                    <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_os}"/></td>
                    <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_examp}"/></td>
                    <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_att}"/></td>
                    <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.total}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:if>

        </c:forEach>
  %>
    </table>

    <form method="post" action="index.jsp">
        <input type="submit" value="Tilbage">
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: What Exception do you get, can you provide a stackTrace?

Comment: Not getting an exception. The code works, but the table is never filled out from the database because selected inside <c:if test="${user.fullname eq selected}"> is nothing it's just empty and it will never display anything in the table. I just want a variable String inside the tags. It works if I write <c:if test="${user.fullname eq 'name'}"> but then it will only always display the same name. I want to be able to select a name from a drop down list, then press a button that takes me to a new page. From there I want to fill out a table with data from my database associated with that name.

Comment: Put this code before your table <%
  String selected = (String)request.getParameter("dropselect");
  out.println("selected value =" + selected);
%> make sure the value is not null. that line logically should be out your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parameter dropselect is not null, can you try this code

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link href="newcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>Full name</th>
    <th>SQL</th>
    <th>Collection</th>
    <th>Req</th>
    <th>OS</th>
    <th>Exam Project</th>
    <th>Attendance</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
    <c:if test="${user.fullname eq param.dropselect}">
      <tr>
        <td id="id"><c:out value="${user.id}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.fullname}"/></td>
        <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_sql}"/></td>
        <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_coll}"/></td>
        <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_req}"/></td>
        <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_os}"/></td>
        <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_examp}"/></td>
        <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.sp_att}"/></td>
        <td id="midt"><c:out value="${user.total}"/></td>
      </tr>
    </c:if>

  </c:forEach>
</table>

<form method="post" action="index.jsp">
  <input type="submit" value="Tilbage">
</form>

</body>
```